# IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> - no duplicate IEnumerable<int>s

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I'm trying to find a solution to this problem:

Given a IEnumerable< IEnumerable< int>> I need a method/algorithm that returns the input, but in case of several IEnmerable< int> with the same elements only one per coincidence/group is returned.

ex.

```
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> seqs = new[]
    { 
        new[]{2,3,4}, // #0 
        new[]{1,2,4}, // #1 - equals #3
        new[]{3,1,4}, // #2
        new[]{4,1,2}  // #3 - equals #1
    };
```

"foreach seq in seqs" .. yields {#0,#1,#2} or {#0,#2,#3}

Sould I go with ..

.. some clever IEqualityComparer

.. some clever LINQ combination I havent figured out - groupby, sequenceequal ..?

.. some seq->HashSet stuff

.. what not. Anything will help

I'll be able to solve it by good'n'old programming but inspiration is always appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a slightly simpler version of digEmAll's answer:

```
var result = seqs.Select(x => new HashSet<int>(x))
                 .Distinct(HashSet<int>.CreateSetComparer());
```

Given that you want to treat the elements *as* sets, you should have them that way to start with, IMO.

Of course this won't help if you want to maintain order within the sequences that are returned, you just don't mind *which* of the equal sets is returned... the above code will  return an `IEnumerable<HashSet<int>>` which will no longer have any ordering within each sequence. (The order in which the *sets* are returned isn't guaranteed either, although it would be odd for them not to be return in first-seen-first-returned basis.)

It feels unlikely that this wouldn't be enough, but if you could give more details of what you really need to achieve, that would make it easier to help.

As noted in comments, this will also assume that there are no duplicates *within* each original source array... or at least, that they're irrelevant, so you're happy to treat { 1 } and { 1, 1, 1, 1 } as equal.

Comment: +1 Nice, but you should warn the OP abut a) different frequencies of duplicates causing issues b) the fact that this trashes the ordering of the numbers within each array c) The fact this is not really returning members of the original source-sequence.

Comment: @Ani: I had already mentioned about trashing the order of numbers within the array, but I've now made that more explicit. Will add a bit about duplicates within each array.

Comment: @Ani: No worries - and it's a good catch about the duplicates within arrays :)

Comment: Isn't this a good occasion to use your ArrayEqualityComparer<T>?  or similar? :)

Comment: @Ani: Not in this case - because that's order-dependent.

Answer (score 4):

Use the correct collection type for the job. What you really want is `ISet<IEnumerable<int>>` with an equality comparer that will ignore the ordering of the `IEnumerable`s.

Answer (score 3):

**EDITED:**

You can get what you want by building your own `IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<int>>` e.g.:

```
public class MyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<int>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<int> x, IEnumerable<int> y)
    {
        return x.OrderBy(el1 => el1).SequenceEqual(y.OrderBy(el2 => el2));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<int> elements)
    {
        int hash = 0;
        foreach (var el in elements)
        {
            hash = hash ^ el.GetHashCode();
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var values = seqs.Distinct(new MyEqualityComparer()).ToList();
```

---

**N.B.**

this solution is slightly different from the one given by Jon Skeet.
His answer considers sublists as **sets**, so basically two lists like `[1,2]` and `[1,1,1,2,2]` are equal.

This solution don't, i.e. :
`[1,2,1,1]` is equal to `[2,1,1,1]` but not to `[2,2,1,1]`, hence basically the two lists have to contain the same elements and in the same number of occurrences.

Comment: +1: Never heard of `HashSet<T>.CreateSetComparer`. But this isn't entirely correct though; I think the last bit should be `.Select(g => g.First()).ToList();`

Comment: The `Where` clause shouldn't be there I think.

Comment: @Ani: Yes, you're right, actually I mis-read the OP question (I don't know why, but I thought he want to exclude the sublists occurring more than once... O_O). So Distinct is far preferable than groupby-select first...

Comment: Given that my previous solution was partially wrong, and basically the same as Jon Skeet, I've changed approach ;)

Comment: Thanks digEmAll. I got a brush up on my IEqualityComparer from this :)